# How can I make the propeller to rotate?

Tags: animation

This is my propeller:

[image: Propeller]

And I'm trying to make it rotating like in this video tutorial:

[Propeller rotation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1sOFEG1UvI)

At [2:22](https://youtu.be/d1sOFEG1UvI?t=2m22s) in the video he clicks on the automatic key frame button, so I did it too. Then I moved the frame green line to the end (250). Then clicked <kbd>N</kbd> and under *Rotation* I changed the 'z' axis to 5000. Then I moved the green bar back to frame 0 and clicked on *Play* but it's not rotating.

Also I saw he is using a bone? Or something so he could rotate first the propeller with the mouse before making the animation.

Not sure how I messed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He pressed "G" to grab and then just clicked the mouse.  What that did is give Blender a detectable action.  In other words, if your grabbing then you're probably moving something, so Blender will automatically insert a keyframe at the current frame.  It's a little hacky.

A better (and more deliberate) way to do this, in my opinion, is to press <kbd>i</kbd> whenever you want to insert a keyframe.  Just select the action that you want to keyframe.  <kbd>i</kbd> works on almost everything, even things like shader nodes.  Using this method prevents you from keyframing things you never intended.

[image]

***EDIT:*** There are whole videos and articles dedicated to keyframing.  But I'll add this: by default, Blender will "curve" the value.  In other words, say for instance a car... going from rest to full speed takes time.  In the same way, Blender automatically *accelerates* to the desired "speed" or value and then decelerates at the end.

You can change the **interpolation** to be **linear** in the ***Graph Editor***:

[image]

Comment: I managed to do it by adding to key frames. One in frame 10 and the second one in the end last frame 250. Only if i set a ket frame in the end the last frame it will  spin. And i changed the Z axis on rotation to 5000. But once i'm doing play and it's getting to frame 10 it start rotating and get faster but then very fast get slower then stop just before the last frame. How can i make it rotate non stop ? And how can i control the speed ? In the Active Keying Set i selected: Rotation. But maybe i need to select something else ?

Comment: Your solution is working great.

Comment: @danielllee - I edited the answer to address some of your questions.  The speed is controlled by how many rotations you set for the length of time between keyframes.  If this answers your original question, please consider marking it as "Accepted".  Thank you